# webservices in PHP and json using codeigniter

Tags: php, json, web-services, codeigniter

I am trying to create and use a webservice which will take input in json and provide output in same.
But it is not able to provide the output correctly.

```
    function login() {
    $data = array(
        'login_id' => $this -> input -> post('login_id'),  
        'login_pwd' => md5($this -> input -> post('login_pwd')),

    );
    $data_string = json_encode($data);
    echo $data_string;
    $ch = curl_init(base_url().'admin_service/getUser');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
       'Content-Type: application/json',
       'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
    );

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    $contenttype = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($result) {
        redirect(base_url() . '/success');
    } else {
        redirect(base_url(). 'relogin'); 
        }
    }
 }
```

Below code is for my webservice:

```
   function getUser_post() {
    $name = $this->post('login_id');
    $password = $this->post('login_pwd');

    $this -> load -> model('register_model');
    // calling the function in our login model
    $result = $this -> register_model -> get_user($name, $password);

    echo $result;
    return json_encode( array('result' => $result ) );

}
```

Problem is: I am not gettign proper json response back in controller. All I am gettting is 1.

I want to get additional information back from webservice. How can I send it back from webservice here.

Any help appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you call your webservice directly (`base_url().'admin_service/getUser'`) with post data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it. You need to echo the `json_encode` result back, not the `$result` which is probably a boolean.

```
function getUser_post() {
    $name = $this->post('login_id');
    $password = $this->post('login_pwd');

    $this -> load -> model('register_model');
    // calling the function in our login model
    $result = $this -> register_model -> get_user($name, $password);

    echo json_encode( array('result' => $result ) );
    return $result;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This CI rest server is quite nice and works in most cases: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver You'll have to adapt your code, but maybe this will help you nevertheless. I can definitely recommend it!

Answer (score 0):

```
function contact()
{

    if ($this->isPOST())
    {      

         $this->form_validation->set_rules('nMobile', 'mobileno', 'trim|required');
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('vEmail', 'email', 'trim|required');
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('vMessage', 'message', 'trim|required');

         $this->form_validation->set_rules('nUserId', 'Userid', 'trim|required');
         //$this->form_validation->set_rules('isActive', 'isActive', 'trim|required');

       if ($this->form_validation->run())
        {
         $nMobile      = $this->input->post('nMobile'); 

         $vEmail      = $this->input->post('vEmail');

         $vMessage     = $this->input->post('vMessage');

         $nUserId      = $this->input->post('nUserId');


         date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); 


         $dCreatedDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

         //$isActive      = $this->input->post('isActive');  


         if(!$nMobile || !$vEmail || !$vMessage || !$nUserId)
            {

                $this->response("Enter Complete User contact information to Save. Field Missing", 201);

            }
            else{


                  $result = $this->User->usercontact(array( "nMobile"=>$nMobile, "vEmail"=>$vEmail, "vMessage"=>$vMessage, "nUserId"=>$nUserId, "dCreatedDate"=>$dCreatedDate, "isActive"=>1));



                 if($result === 0)
                    {

                        $this->response("User contact information could not be saved. Try again.", 404);

                    }
                    else{


                            $this->status = Ws_Controller::HTTP_OK;
                            $this->responseData = array();

                            $this->message = "User contact information successfully inserted";


                        }

                }

        } else
            {
              $this->status = Ws_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST;

              $this->message = strip_tags($this->form_validation->error_string());
            }       
    }
 else
    {
        $this->status = Ws_Controller::HTTP_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED;
        $this->message = lang('err_invalid_method');
    }

}
```